# Natural Sorting Datatable.js

Tags: datatables

Natural sorting in datatable.js

Using this javascript fuctionnaturalSort(a, b) we can any datatype column sorting

Example: we want sorting is datatable like 1,101,99,88,103

We can use this and result will be 1,88,99,101,103

```
        function naturalSort(a, b) {

            // setup temp-scope variables for comparison evauluation

            var x = a.toString().toLowerCase() || '', y = b.toString().toLowerCase() || '',
            nC = String.fromCharCode(0),
            xN = x.replace(/([-]{0,1}[0-9.]{1,})/g, nC + '$1' + nC).split(nC),
            yN = y.replace(/([-]{0,1}[0-9.]{1,})/g, nC + '$1' + nC).split(nC),
            xD = (new Date(x)).getTime(), yD = (new Date(y)).getTime();

            // natural sorting of dates

            if (xD && yD && xD < yD)
                return -1;
            else if (xD && yD && xD > yD)
                return 1;

            // natural sorting through split numeric strings and default strings
            for (var cLoc = 0, numS = Math.max(xN.length, yN.length) ; cLoc < numS; cLoc++)
                if ((parseFloat(xN[cLoc]) || xN[cLoc]) < (parseFloat(yN[cLoc]) || yN[cLoc]))
                    return -1;
                else if ((parseFloat(xN[cLoc]) || xN[cLoc]) > (parseFloat(yN[cLoc]) || yN[cLoc]))
                    return 1;
            return 0;
        }

        jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['natural-asc'] = function (a, b) {
            return naturalSort(a, b);
        };

        jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['natural-desc'] = function (a, b) {
           return naturalSort(a, b) * -1;
        };
```

Add aocolumns in datatable properties and put sType is natual.

```
       aoColumns: [
            { "sType": "natural" }
        ],
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you're sharing your code or asking for help?

Comment: this code for helping natural sorting